# Solving a second order differential equation using the method of undetermined coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:

Find the general solution of the following differential equation.
$$ y'' + 2y' + 4y = 13 \cos(4x) $$

Answer:

So the first step is to find the complementary solution, $y_c$.
\begin{align*}
m^2 +2m + 4 &= 0 \\
m &= \dfrac{ -2 \pm \sqrt{ 4 - 4(1)(4)} }{ 2(1)} \\
m &= \dfrac{ -2 \pm \sqrt{ -12 } }{ 2 } \\
m &= -1 \pm \sqrt{3} i \\
\end{align*}
Now we have:
$$ y_c = e^{-x} ( c_1 \sin( \sqrt{ 3 }x ) + c_2 \cos( \sqrt{ 3 } x ) )$$.
Now we need to find $y_p$.
\begin{align*}
y_p &= A \cos(4x) + B \sin(4x) \\
y'_p &= - 4A \sin(4x) + 4B \cos(4x) \\
y''_p &= - 16A \cos(4x) - 16B \sin(4x) \\
\end{align*}
Let $LHS = y'' + 2y' + 4y $. We have:
\begin{align*}
LHS &= - 16A \cos(4x) - 16B \sin(4x) + \\
    &2 ( - 4A \sin(4x) + 4B \cos(4x)  )
 + 4( A \cos(4x) + B \sin(4x) ) \\
%
LHS &=
 - 16A \cos(4x) - 16B \sin(4x) - 8A \sin(4x) + \\
    & 8B \cos(4x) + 4A \cos(4x) + 4B \sin(4x) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
- 16A \cos(4x) - 16B \sin(4x) - 8A \sin(4x) + 8B \cos(4x) + \\
 & 4A \cos(4x) + 4B \sin(4x) \\
    &= 13 \cos(4x) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
- 12A \cos(4x) - 16B \sin(4x) - 8A \sin(4x) + 8B \cos(4x)
  + 4B \sin(4x) &= 13 \cos(4x) \\
%
- 12A \cos(4x) - 12B \sin(4x) - 8A \sin(4x) + 8B \cos(4x) &= 13 \cos(4x)
\end{align*}
Now we set up the following system of linear equations:
\begin{align*}
-12A + 8B &= 13 \\
-12B - 8A &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
We rewrite as:
\begin{align*}
-12A + 8B &= 13 \\
2A + 3B &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Now we solve the system of equations:
\begin{align*}
A &= \left( - \dfrac{ 3 }{2} \right) B \\
-12 \left( \dfrac{-3B}{2} \right) + 8B &= 13 \\
18B + 8B &= 13 \\
B &= 2 \\
A &= -3 \\
\end{align*}
Hence our answer is:
$$ y = e^{-x} ( c_1 \sin( \sqrt{ 3 }x ) + c_2 \cos( \sqrt{ 3 } x ) ) +
  + 48 \cos(4x) - 32 \sin(4x)   $$
However, the book's answer is:
$$ y = e^{-x} ( c_1 \sin( \sqrt{ 3 }x ) + c_2 \cos( \sqrt{ 3 } x ) ) +
  \left( \dfrac{1}{2}\right) \sin(4x) - \dfrac{3 }{4} - \cos(4x) $$
Where did I go wrong?

Based upon the comments made by user170231 I have updated my answer. However, it is still wrong. Here is the updated answer:

So the first step is to find the complementary solution, $y_c$.
\begin{align*}
m^2 +2m + 4 &= 0 \\
m &= \dfrac{ -2 \pm \sqrt{ 4 - 4(1)(4)} }{ 2(1)} \\
m &= \dfrac{ -2 \pm \sqrt{ -12 } }{ 2 } \\
m &= -1 \pm \sqrt{3} i \\
\end{align*}
Now we have:
$$ y_c = e^{-x} ( c_1 \sin( \sqrt{ 3 }x ) + c_2 \cos( \sqrt{ 3 } x ) )$$.
Now we need to find $y_p$.
\begin{align*}
y_p &= A \cos(4x) + B \sin(4x) \\
y'_p &= - 4A \sin(4x) + 4B \cos(4x) \\
y''_p &= - 16A \cos(4x) - 16B \sin(4x) \\
\end{align*}
Let $LHS = y'' + 2y' + 4y $. We have:
\begin{align*}
LHS &=
- 16A \cos(4x) - 16B \sin(4x) + 2 ( - 4A \sin(4x) + 4B \cos(4x)  ) \\
 &+ 4( A \cos(4x) + B \sin(4x) ) \\
%
LHS &=
 - 16A \cos(4x) - 16B \sin(4x) - 8A \sin(4x) \\
   &+ 8B \cos(4x) \\
 & + 4A \cos(4x) + 4B \sin(4x) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
- 16A \cos(4x) - 16B \sin(4x) - 8A \sin(4x) \\
   & + 8B \cos(4x) \\
 &+ 4A \cos(4x) + 4B \sin(4x) \\
 &= 13 \cos(4x) \\
%
- 12A \cos(4x) - 16B \sin(4x) \\
    &- 8A \sin(4x) + 8B \cos(4x) \\
  + 4B \sin(4x) &= 13 \cos(4x) \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
- 12A \cos(4x) - 12B \sin(4x) - 8A \sin(4x) \\
 &+ 8B \cos(4x) \\
&= 13 \cos(4x)
\end{align*}
Now we set up the following system of linear equations:
\begin{align*}
-12A + 8B &= 13 \\
-12B - 8A &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
We rewrite as:
\begin{align*}
-12A + 8B &= 13 \\
2A + 3B &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Now we solve the system of equations:
\begin{align*}
A &= \left( - \dfrac{ 3 }{2} \right) B \\
-12 \left( \dfrac{-3B}{2} \right) + 8B &= 13 \\
18B + 8B &= 13 \\
26B &= 13 \\
B &= \dfrac{1}{2} \\
A &= \left( \dfrac{-3}{2}\right) \left( \dfrac{1}{2} \right) \\
A &= - \dfrac{ 3 }{4 }
\end{align*}
Hence our answer is:
$$ y = e^{-x} ( c_1 \sin( \sqrt{ 3 }x ) + c_2 \cos( \sqrt{ 3 } x ) )
  - \dfrac{ 3 }{4 } \cos(4x)  + \dfrac{1}{2} \sin(4x)   $$
However, the book's answer is:
$$ y = e^{-x} ( c_1 \sin( \sqrt{ 3 }x ) + c_2 \cos( \sqrt{ 3 } x ) ) +
  \left( \dfrac{1}{2}\right) \sin(4x) - \dfrac{3 }{4} - \cos(4x) $$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Simple arithmetic error: $18B+8B=26B=13$ means $B=\dfrac12$

Comment: First thing to do is to plug in your answer, and plug in their answer, and see which one actually satisfies the equation. After all, it could be that the book is wrong & you are right.

Comment: (1) The ansatz contains $A\cos(4x)$, not just a constant term $A$. (2) The book's answer has a typo, there should be no minus sign between $\cos(4x)$ and its coefficient.

Comment: Right answer is $y = e^{-x} ( c_1 \sin( \sqrt{ 3 }x ) + c_2 \cos( \sqrt{ 3 } x ) ) + \dfrac{1}{2} \sin(4x) - \dfrac{3 }{4}  \cos(4x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in solving these differential equations is the determination of a particular solution. In this case this can be simple: considering instead

$$
y''+2y'+4y = 13 e^{4 ix}
$$

and taking $y_p = c e^{i\alpha x}$ after substitution we have

$$
(\alpha  (\alpha -2 i)-4) c e^{i \alpha  x}+13 e^{4 i x}=0,\forall x
$$

so $\alpha = 4$ resulting in

$$
(3+2 i-3) (4 c+(3+2 i)) e^{4 i x}=0 \Rightarrow c = -\frac 34-\frac i2
$$

and

$$
y_p = -\left(\frac 34+\frac i2\right)\left(\cos(4x)+i\sin(4x)\right)
$$

and finally

$$
\mathcal{R}\left[y_p\right] = \frac 12\sin(4x)-\frac 34\cos(4x)
$$